# Compress Linux Kernel with xz

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, xz

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to compress the Linux kernel with xz, and if so, how would I go about this? I actually tried compressing a raw kernel image with xz [a silly idea] and loading it from the grub prompt and got the following:

```
grub> linux /vmlinuz-6.0.5.xz root=/dev/sda2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait ro
Invalid magic number
grub>
```

Like I stated before, this was a hopeless idea and I had expected an error. But is there an actual method of compressing the Linux kernel with xz?

Please note that I normally develop for Raspberry Pi, so some configuration options available in x86_64 may not be present there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can compress the kernel with `xz`. When you configure it, under “General setup”, you’ll find a configuration item named “Kernel compression mode”; if `xz` is available, you’ll be able [to choose “XZ” there](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.1/source/init/Kconfig#L292). Build your kernel as usual (`make bzImage` for example) and it will be compressed with `xz` (and bootable).

This option [is available on ARM](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.1.1/source/arch/arm/Kconfig#L107).